# How to calculate the maximum sum in a reverse way in pandas list

Tags: python, pandas, list, counter

I have this list:

```
balance = [300,400,250,100,50,1,2,0,10,15,25,20,10,1,0,10,15]
```

I need to calculate the maximum consecutive increase in balance over a certain period of time.
The first element on the right is the most recent.

For example, I need to calculate the maximum consecutive increases in balance over the most recent 10 occurrences.
From the list above, I'd take the most recent 10 occurrences:

`[0,10,15,25,20,10,1,0,10,15]`

Count the consecutive increases (by adding 1 every time there is an increase, else reset the counter):

```
[0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0,1,2]
```

And then take the maximum (which is 3).

Does anyone know how to code it in Python?

Comment: Did you considered use pandas for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do in plain(vanilla) python like this:

```
c=0
r = [0,10,15,25,20,10,1,0,10,15]
k=[]
for x in range(len(r)-1):
  if r[x]<r[x+1]:
    c+=1
    k.append(c)
  else:
    c=0
    k.append(c)

print(k)
[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2]

print(max(k))
3
```